# Android : Application is running on background or foreground? :S

Tags: android, background-process, android-3.0-honeycomb, background-foreground

I have wrote an application and dont want to do anything other than my application on installed device. But in Android 3.x versions, i couldn't disable the status bar programmaticaly. Then  i have to check the application, when it is BACKed and returned to device desktop, and when it is returned and worked on my application. Is there a way to check that application is active on foreground or invisible but runnning on background?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity, onResume will be called when it becomes visible and onPause will be called when it is no longer visible.

See here for more detailed info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html